# specify name of dropdownlist asp.net mvc3 razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am wondering why the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Classification.Nationality.NationalityId", Model.Nationalities, new { @size = 10, @style = "display:none;", @class = "pickList" })
```

produces the following html, specifically why the name of the element is not "Classification.Nationality.NationalityId".

```
<select style="display: none;" size="10" name="CollectionCategory.Classification.Nationality.NationalityId" id="CollectionCategory_Classification_Nationality_NationalityId" class="pickList">
```

where the function signature sure looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes);
```

It seems like the name parameter gots overriden by view model of the parent view. ( This is in a partial view). Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are calling this helper inside an editor template or partial for a navigational property called `CollectionCategory`. It's perfectly normal behavior and ensures that proper value is sent to the controller action when binding. Also I would recommend you using the strongly typed version of this helper to avoid those refactor unfriendly magic strings:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Classification.Nationality.NationalityId, 
    Model.Nationalities, 
    new { 
        @size = 10, 
        @style = "display:none;", 
        @class = "pickList" 
    }
)
```

Of course if you don't want to follow conventions (no idea why wouldn't you) but you could specify a binding prefix in your POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo([Bind(Prefix = "CollectionCategory")] ClassificationViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I had started along those lines. The issue lies in the fact that this is a reused component that has javascript functionality, so the id's of the components are important for the client side script. I could have a property on the view model like "ModelPrefix" or something to handle this, I suppose. You have answered my question as to why this is happening. Thanks.